# 'str' object is not callable site

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

When I execute the code I'm having an error and I don't get why!
I'm taking this code from a page and normally their code should work but it's not working

```
    for tweet2 in find:
        file = open( 'tweets.txt', 'a' )
        print( "name:", tweet2.author.name )
        print( "Screen-name:", tweet2.author.screen_name )
        print( "Tweet created :", tweet2.created_at )
        print( "tweet:", tweet2.text )
        print( "Retweeted:", tweet2.retweeted )
        print( "language:", tweet2.lang )
        print( "Location:", tweet2.user.location )
        print( "Time-zone:", tweet2.user.time_zone )
        print( "Geo:", tweet2.geo )
        print( "Hashtages:", tweet2.entities.get( 'hashtags' ) )
        print( "------------------------------------" )

        file.write(
            'Name:s\nScreen-Name:s\nCreated_at:s\nTweet-Text:s\nRetweeted:s\nlanguage:s\nLocation:s\nTime_zone:'(
            tweet2.author.name, tweet2.author.screen_name, tweet2.created_at, tweet2.text,
            tweet2.retweeted ,tweet2.lang ,tweet2.user.location,tweet2.user.time_zone,tweet2.geo))
    file.close()
    -------------------------------


    Tweet created : 2018-01-29 17:09:35
    tweet2.lang ,tweet2.user.location,tweet2.user.time_zone,tweet2.geo))
tweet: Python for Beginners with Examples
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any suggestions? thanks in advance

Comment: check if you have a local variable called `str` that is hiding the buildin `str` function

Comment: The error is with `file.write()` - You are not formatting the string correctly and instead trying to call it like a function with parenthesis directly after a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `file.write()` function to

```
file.write('Name:{}\nScreen-Name:{}\nCreated_at:{}\nTweet-Text:{}\nRetweeted:{}\nlanguage:{}\nLocation:{}\nTime_zone:{}'.format(tweet2.author.name, tweet2.author.screen_name, tweet2.created_at, tweet2.text, tweet2.retweeted ,tweet2.lang ,tweet2.user.location,tweet2.user.time_zone))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem.

```
file.write(
        'Name:s\nScreen-Name:s\nCreated_at:s\nTweet-Text:s\nRetweeted:s\nlanguage:s\nLocation:s\nTime_zone:'(
        tweet2.author.name, tweet2.author.screen_name, tweet2.created_at, tweet2.text,
        tweet2.retweeted ,tweet2.lang ,tweet2.user.location,tweet2.user.time_zone,tweet2.geo))
```

This part is a string:

```
'Name:s\nScreen-Name:s\nCreated_at:s\nTweet-Text:s\nRetweeted:s\nlanguage:s\nLocation:s\nTime_zone:'(
```

And immediately following it you have an opening parenthesis. This is a function call. You are trying to call that string like a function. Python rightly calls you out on this BS.

I assume you want to write the other values to the file as part of the string, probably where you have `s`. This should be `%s` and you should use the `%` operator between the string and the values. As sng notes in a comment, you also appear to be missing a placeholder and also may not have the right number of values. As a first attempt, change that line to:

```
'Name:%s\nScreen-Name:%s\nCreated_at:%s\nTweet-Text:%s\nRetweeted:%s\nlanguage:%s\nLocation:%s\nTime_zone:%s' % (
```

You can also use `.format()` as A Magoon suggests; it's the newer way to do this. I suggested `%` because it looks like what you were trying to do.

Comment: The string also needs a placeholder for `Time_zone`. Also, I think the number of placeholders does not match the number of values in the tuple.

Comment: Fixed the missing placeholder. Whoops! As for the number of items, OP is on their own there....

Comment: Yeah, they are on their own. Just wanted to highlight that :)